# Laravel How to post request populate my array values into modal?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Hi I am currently doing a appointment form where the user selects the date and time range he wants to book an appointment. I want to show the array of results on a modal upon clicking the search button and populate the array of results on my modal as

> @forelse ($dt as $dt).

Below is my blade.php view page:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{ route('assistant.newappts.new') }}" method="POST">
            @method('post')
            @csrf
            <label for="select_date">Select Date:</label>
            <input type="text" id="select_date" class="form-control" name="select_date" placeholder="Select Date">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <div class="half-form">
                @foreach ($operatinghrs as $operatinghr)
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="starttime">Choose Start Time </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="time" id="start_time" name="start_time" min="{{display24HTime($operatinghr->start_time)}}" max="{{display24HTime($operatinghr->end_time)}}" value="{{ display24HTime(old('start_time', $operatinghr->start_time))}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="starttime">Choose End Time</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="time" id="end_time" name="end_time" min="{{display24HTime($operatinghr->start_time)}}" max="{{display24HTime($operatinghr->end_time)}}" value="{{ display24HTime(old('end_time', $operatinghr->end_time))}}">
                    <div class="form-update" style="float:right;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" id="find_appointment_btn">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach             
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
@overwrite

@section('modal')
<!-- MODAL NEW APPOINTMENT -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalNewAppointment">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select Appointment</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="timeslots-section">
                        <div class="timeslots text-center">
                            @forelse ($dt as $dt)
                                <div class="timeslot">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="timeslotchk" name="timeslot" value="{{$dt}}">
                                    {{$dt}}
                                </div>
                            @empty
                            <div class="empty" style="text-align: left">No appointments available.</div>
                            @endforelse
                        </div> <!-- end timeslots -->
                    </div>
                </div>
               
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="new_appt_save_btn" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> saving..">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="close_btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@overwrite
```

Below is my javascript for the blade.php view page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select_date').datepicker({      
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            toggleActive: true
        }); 

        $('#find_appointment_btn').click(function() {
            $('#myModalNewAppointment').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
            $('#myModalNewAppointment .modal-title').html('New Appointment');
        });
    })

</script>
```

Below is my controller class method for the on page load and the post request method for getting the appointment timings:

```
public function index()
    {
        if ($_SESSION['user_role'] != 'Assistant') {
            return "Unauthorized Access";
        }
        $workinghr = WorkingHour::where('clinic_id', $_SESSION['clinic_ID'])->where('off_day', false)->pluck('day')->toArray();
        
        $todayday = Carbon::now('Asia/Singapore')->format('l');
        $operatinghrs = $this->getWorkDayTiming($todayday);

        $data = [
            'link_menu_appt' => 'open active',
            'link_newappt' => 'active',                       
            'operatinghrs' => $operatinghrs,            
        ];

        return view('patient_appointment.available-appointment', $data);
    }

    public function filterByDate(Request $request)
    {
        $dateselected = $request->select_date;
        $starttime = $request->start_time;
        $endtime = $request->end_time;
        
        $dtarray = $this->getSelectedDate($dateselected, $starttime, $endtime);
        $dt = array_slice($dtarray, 0, 12, true);

        $todayday = Carbon::now('Asia/Singapore')->format('l');
        $operatinghrs = $this->getWorkDayTiming($todayday);
        
        $data = [
            'link_appt' => 'active',                   
            'operatinghrs' => $operatinghrs,       
            'dt' => $dt,                
        ];

        return view('patient_appointment.available-appointment', $data);

    }
```

Comment: Even though this approach is possible you would normally make an ajax request to the server and return the data as response instead of loading the whole page again. Vue.js would be of good use here but you could also make it work with basic JS and JQuery. If you really want to do it the current way you will pass a variable to the view to indicate that the modal has to be automatically opened  and the possible results.
Or what makes you the problem?

Comment: hi @Aless55 thanks for your input! Is there documentation where I can learn about making an ajax request to the server and return the data as response? I would like to make on page load to be just the form, and after submitting the inputs required, the modal will show together with the array of data.

Comment: There is no official doc because it has nothing directly to do with Laravel. If you google "Laravel post ajax tutorial" you should find some good tutorials that show you the direction. Otherwise Vue.js is always worth a try, there are also countless tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

For the JS part you will have to do something like that:
You will get all the data of your input field and send it via the ajax request to your defined route. (don't forget the csrf token)

```
<script>

  $("#find_appointment_btn").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      let start = $("input[name=start_time]").val();
      let end = $("input[name=end_time]").val();
      let date = $("input[name=date]").val();
      let _token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

      $.ajax({
        url: "/YOUR_URL_HERE",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
          start_time:start,
          end_time:end,
          date: date,
          _token: _token
        },
        success:function(response){
          console.log(response);
          //display the result if no error occurred with help of JS
        },
       });
  });
</script>
```

In your Controller you can do the same things as before, but you will have to return a response:

```
    public function filterByDate(Request $request)
    {
        $dateselected = $request->select_date;
        $starttime = $request->start_time;
        $endtime = $request->end_time;
        
        $dtarray = $this->getSelectedDate($dateselected, $starttime, $endtime);
        $dt = array_slice($dtarray, 0, 12, true);

        $todayday = Carbon::now('Asia/Singapore')->format('l');
        $operatinghrs = $this->getWorkDayTiming($todayday);
        
        $data = [
            'link_appt' => 'active',                   
            'operatinghrs' => $operatinghrs,       
            'dt' => $dt,                
        ];

        return response->json($data, 200);

    }
```

I hope this guides you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You could preferably achieve this with Laravel API calls via Axios—a lightweight javascript library that enables you to perform AJAX operations without having to bear the burden of loading a heavyweight library like Jquery (i.e. if all you're going to use it is for making AJAX calls).

Creating Laravel API routes is exactly the same as creating Laravel web routes. The only difference is that the API routes you create reside under `yourdomain.com/api/{route-url}` instead of `yourdomain.com/{route-url}`.

Once you have your APIs setup, you can use a simple API testing client like Postman to ensure your APIs are returning the expected results.

All that's left now is to make XML-HTTP requests to your API via Axios.

You can install and inject `axios` as a dependency on your project by running the following commands (assuming you already have node installed) on your terminal within your project root directory:

```
npm install           //install dependencies listed in your package.json
npm install axios     //install axios if it is not listed in your package.json
```

You can check your existing node dependencies in the `package.json` file (in your project root directory).

Once you have your dependencies sorted, you can simply import Axios into your JS file as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

And now that we're all set, with each click of the form submit or load button or any JS event for that matter, you can trigger the Axios XML-HTTP requests using the `axios.get()`, `axios.post()`, `axios.put()` and `axios.delete()` methods.

A typical Javascript Axios request would look something as follows:

```
axios.<request type, i.e. get, post etc>('<request url>' + <wild card query data>,
{
    //parse & manipulate data
})
.then(response =>
{
    if(check if response was successful)
    {
        //trigger some event like page reload or show the modal in your case
    }
}
.catch(error => 
{
    //handle error
})
```